# How can I bind View to ViewCell in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I'm doing an MVVM app and have a problem: I need to dynamically create an interface in the app. So I created a ViewModel with `Collection`.

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewCell> dataTemplate { get; set; }
```

And add a button that's add new element of it

```
private void NewOther(object obj)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {                
            ViewCell other = new ViewCell
            {
                View = new StackLayout
                {
                    Children = { new Label { Text = "I m New" } }
                }

            };
            
            dataTemplate.Add(other);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        } 
    }
```

In Xaml I have:

```
<RefreshView Padding="5" Command="{Binding LoadCheckListsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">            
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding dataTemplate}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
                    <Button Text="Add Measurment" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding AddMeasurment}"/>
                    <Button Text="Add Pattern" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding AddPattern}"/>
                    <Button Text="Add Other" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding AddOther}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                    <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Footer>
            
            
        </ListView>
    </RefreshView>
```

So, after I press `AddOther`, I have a new element with text "Xamrin.Forms.ViewCell", I think this is just `viewcell.ToString()`.

**How can I bind the content of view cell here?**

Comment: Yes, by default the ListView and CollectionView uses the `ToString()`. You might have to declare the `ListView.ItemTemplate` in the XAML.

Comment: IMHO, this question is not clear. "Binding" in MVVM refers to binding some **model** object (NOT a UI object such as "a view") to a UI object (here, "a viewcell"). The title of question says "bind view to viewcell". The xaml in question shows (correct) bindings to properties on the viewmodel. Unclear what "bind the content of view cell here" is referring to. ...

Comment: ... In addition, there are multiple problems with what is being attempted. ListView is a binding between an ItemsSource and an ItemTemplate. Meaningless to add another viewcell directly. Second, **programmatically adding UI** with mvvm won't work with "Binding" - there isn't a way to add the corresponding **model** property to the vm. To be useful to anyone, this question needs to describe the user experience that is intended. And question asker needs to consider what data they need to store, to accomplish the goal. Only then can "UI approaches" be considered.

Comment: ... "dynamically create an interface" is a potentially huge design space. In practice, what an app developer does is **limit** what the user can add. Define several `data templates` that can be used in `view cells`. Define one or several `layouts` within which cells can be placed. Only then does the coder have a practical design, which they can attempt to implement - and come to StackOverflow if stuck on some specific implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement , you have to know that

1. We often use `Data` as source and bind it to the control/layout , it is incorrect to set `View` as source directly.
2. ListView shares the same Template , that means the rows should be same , we can't add different template at runtime .

---

As a workaround , we can use `TableView`.

`TableView`   does not have the concept of an `ItemsSource` , so items must be manually added as children.

#### sample code

```
//xaml
<TableView>
     <TableSection x:Name="section">
          <ImageCell ImageSource="dog.png"/>
          <SwitchCell On="True"/>
      </TableSection>
</TableView>
```

```
//code behind
private void NewOther(object obj){

    ViewCell other = new ViewCell
    {
        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { new Label { Text = "I m New" } }
         }

     };
     section.Add(other);
}
```

#### Screen shot

[image]

#### Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview.

Comment: So, i can't bind cellview even to Tableview?

Comment: yes, can't bind to any sort of layout , but you can add it dynamically in code as the way I provided.